# pl-sql include column names in query

Tags: oracle, plsql

A weird request maybe but. My boss wants me to create an admin version of a page we have that displays data from an oracle query in a table.

The admin page, instead of displaying the data (query returns 1 row), needs to return the table name and column name

Ex: Instead of:

```
Name      Initial
==================
Bob       A
```

I want:

```
Name                 Initial
============================
Users.FirstName      Users.MiddleInitial
```

I realize I can do this in code but would rather just modify the query to return the data I want so I can leave the report generation code mostly alone.

I don't want to do it in a stored procedure.

So when I spit out the data in the report using something like:

```
blah blah = MyDataRow("FirstName")
```

I can leave that as is but instead of it displaying "BOB" it would display "Users.FirstName"

And I want to do the query using select * if possible instead of listing all the columns

So for each of the columns I am querying in the * , I want to get (instead of the column value) the tablename.ColumnName or tablename|columnName

hope you are following- I am confusing myself...

pseudo:

```
select tablename + '.' + Columnname as WhateverTheColumnNameIs 
from Table1 
  left join Table2 on whatever...
  Join Table_Names on blah blah
```

Whew- after writing all this I think I will just do it on the code side.

But if you are up for it maybe a fun challenge

Comment: I don't think this is possible with straight SQL, you will need to write a stored procedure and use dynamic SQL. Btw: the string concatenation operator is `||` not `+`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not provide an authentic way(there is no pseudocolumn) to get the column name of a table as a result of a query against that table. But you might consider these two approaches:

1. Extract column name from an `xmltype`, formed by passing cursor expression(your query) in the `xmltable()` function:

   ```
   -- your table
   with t1(first_name, middle_name) as(
     select 1,2 from dual
   ), -- your query
   t2 as(
      select * --  col1 as "t1.col1"
               --, col2 as "t1.col2"
               --, col3 as "t1.col3" 
       from hr.t1
     )
   select *
     from ( select q.object_value.getrootelement() as col_name
                 , rownum as rn
             from xmltable('//*'
                            passing xmltype(cursor(select * from t2 where rownum = 1))
           ) q
    where q.object_value.getrootelement() not in ('ROWSET', 'ROW')
   )
   pivot(
     max(col_name) for rn in (1 as "name", 2 as "initial")
   )
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   name            initial       
   --------------- ---------------
   FIRST_NAME      MIDDLE_NAME
   ```

   Note: In order for column names to be prefixed with table name, you need to list them
   explicitly in the select list of a query and supply an alias, manually.
2. PL/SQL approach. Starting from Oracle 11g you could use [dbms_sql()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm) package and `describe_columns()` procedure specifically to get the name of columns in the cursor(your select).

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for, try selecting from system views USER_TAB_COLS or ALL_TAB_COLS.